# Terminal: Opening the current path in a window?

Tags: linux, user-interface, ubuntu, directory, terminal

Often times, I find myself navigating very deep into a directory and wanting to open the graphical window (nautilus) for various reasons. So the question is simple:

After doing,

```
cd sampledirectory  
cd sampledirectory2
```

How can I open this location in a GUI?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I assume Gnome with Nautilus:

```
nautilus .
```

To open in the current directory.

Replace nautilus with whichever File Manager you use (Dolphin, etc).

Comment: Cool! I kept trying nautilus and it opened the window in my home directory. Help didn't provide much either.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nick I will check this. mostly i use ALT + F2 command to go to specific directory.

Comment: @Adeel: Yes. That works but I wanted it to instantly open the current location in a GUI file manager...

Comment: Awesome!! :D. I never thought DOT will open the current dir!

Answer (score 9):

The most portable way should be using freedesktop's xdg-utils [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html). For example

```
   $ xdg-open .
```

this has the advantage of choosing from your desktop preferences the tool to open different file types, like for example

```
   $ xdg-open ~/Documents/mypresentation.odp
```

or

```
   $ xdg-open ~/Pictures/mypic.png
```

Comment: xdg-open doesn't quite work for, say, highlighting a file within a directory, but nautilus does (or correct me if I'm wrong...)

Answer (score 5):

```
nautilus --no-desktop . &
```

Comment: Actually typing `nautilus .` opens the window in the background without keeping the terminal busy... Thanks anyways..

Comment: Not in all situations. Such as if you don't normally run nautilus.

Answer (score 4):

### nautilus .

---

I've done this a zillion times.

Here is how I do it on every system:

Mac:

```
#!/bin/sh
open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app ${1:-.}
```

Linux / BSD, if Gnome:

```
#!/bin/sh
nautilus ${1:-.}
```

Windows ... Cygwin ...

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -eq 1 ] && exec explorer "$(cygpath -w "$1")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to DigitalRoss' comment, on a Mac you can add the following to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias finder="open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app ${1:-.}"
```

then, from any Terminal window session, you can simply type:

```
finder
```

to launch the Finder at your current location.

Comment: It's a lot easier just to say `open .`.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised that you all not mention:

```
( dolphin . & )
```

Detaching programs form the terminal is always key for me because when you close the console window after just do

```
dolphin . &
```

... it will also close your file manager or whatever program you started this way together with it and probably nobody wants this.